# Why are my icons and splash screens not appearing in my Phonegap Android app?

Tags: cordova, adt

I am using the Google Android Development Tools (Eclipse) with the Phonegap plugin to build an Android app.

In the directories `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, and `drawable-xhpdi`, I have placed two `.PNG` files. One called `ic_launcher.png` for my launcher icon, and one called `splash.png` for my splash screen. Each one is a custom image of my own creation, and I hope that I have made them the appropriate sizes for each of the four screen dimensions.

However, when I build the `.APK` file, and test it on my phone, the icon is still the default Phonegap icon, and the splash screens do not appear.

How do I get my icons and splash screen PNG files to be built into my `.APK`?

Comment: Are you sure that they were placed inside the folder with correct sizes? That could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to include these two lines in my `MainActivity.java file`, inside the `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 3000);
```

The `3000` refers to the number of miliseconds you want the splash screen open for. I timed mine to be roughly about how long it takes for my program to load anyway.

Also, I then added this to my config.xml at the very end, right before the closing  tag:

```
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

The file names and location as I described in the question were fine as they were.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3 and using phonegap build, see this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3571

See the comment at the bottom (added 19/Aug/13 20:55) with a link to a (user contributed) solution. It uses a cordova hook.

Comment: actually, it is a bug with cordova as you have correctly pointed out. Link to the user contributed script: https://gist.github.com/apla/6179863

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [Phonegap api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen) if you have done perfect job as api than you uninstall application and reinstall because some time cache problem is arise so do not replace our new splash and icon on app

Answer (score 0):

Put your icons into your assets/www/res/icon/android folder. One for each dpi.

Reference these in your config.xml (assuming it is in your www folder)

```
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
```

Similar with your splashscreen

Put it into /res/screen/android folder and reference in config.xml

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
```